# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader Crash app

Tags: java, android

My app is crash and in log I see this :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pl.pgo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/pl.eltegps.pgo-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpackage.so"
```

in this line my apk is crash:

```
    System.loadLibrary("package");
```

And this is my all class

```
public class serial_native {

    private int fd;
    private int delay = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "serial_native";

    public int OpenComPort(String device) 
    {
        fd = openport(device);
        if (fd < 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "native open returns null");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void CloseComPort()
    {
        closeport(fd);
    }

    public byte[] ReadPort(int count)
    {
        return readport(fd, count, delay);
    }

    public int WritePort(byte[] buf)
    {
        return writeport(fd, buf);
    }

    public void ClearBuffer()
    {
        clearportbuf(fd);
    }

    private native int openport(String port);                       //open serial port
    private native void closeport(int fd);                          //close serial port
    private native byte[] readport(int fd, int count, int delay);       //try to read number of count bytes, then return a byte array, which may be shorter than count
    private native int writeport(int fd, byte[] buf);                   //try to write byte array to serialport, may be failed
    private native void clearportbuf(int fd);                               //clear the serialport read/write buffer

    public static boolean libsLoaded = false;
    public static String libsLoadException = null;

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("package");
            System.loadLibrary("lfrfid");
            libsLoaded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            libsLoaded = false;
            libsLoadException = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove all `build` folder from your project and sync gradle.

Comment: @AndiGeeky it doen't help me

Comment: It suggests that your any dependency is using `libpackage.so` file and It is not available. Please check which library using this and add that file to right path!